# FreeBSD 11 doesn't detect internal eMMC 32 GB disk

Tags: freebsd, hard-disk, ssd

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 100S 14'' IBR-14'' with Intel Celeron CPU N3060 @ 1.60GHz, 32GB disk and 4GB RAM; I have booted a couple of times with a FreeBSD 11 install stick but it does not seem to detect the internal eMMC disk.

Linux Mint is able to detect it after disabling Secure Boot in the UEFI BIOS but FreeBSD 11.0 does not, in fact, in `dmesg` the disk does not appear.

What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After several retries, and testing FreeBSD 12.0-Current, I arrived to the conclusion the internal eMMC disk is not supported by FreeBSD 11.0; upon booting with FreeBSD 12.0-current, `dmesg` already showed the internal disk:

```
mmcsd0: 31GB <MMCHC DF4032 0.1 SN 3C4DE893 MFG 11/2016 by 69 0x0000> at mmc0 50.0MHz/8bit/65535-block
mmcsd0boot0: 4MB partion 1 at mmcsd0
mmcsd0boot1: 4MB partion 2 at mmcsd0
mmcsd0rpmb: 4MB partion 3 at mmcsd0
```